# accessing namespace which called a function using builtin dir()

Tags: python, scope

i am having a problem with scope. i would like to have a function  operate on the result of the builtin function `dir()`. so, as a simple example, i want to

```
>>> print (dir())
>>>  .... bunch of stuff ...
```

but, i want define a function which operates on this results of dir(). however, if try this like so

```
>>> def print_dir(dummy_var=None):
        print dir()
>>> print_dir()
>>> ['dummy_var']
```

i cant access the namespace of what called `print_dir` which i understand is a scope thing and makes sense, but is there a way to access the namespace from which a function is called? or do i have to pass the result of dir() to the function? like.

```
>>> act_on_namespace(dir())
```

the specific goal in mind is something like this,

```
def act_on_namespace()
    for k in dir():
        try:
            print(eval(k).__module__)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no straightforward way to manipulate the calling namespace like that.  The simplest way is to do what you already suggested: call `act_on_namespace(dir())`.  If you really want to get crazy, you could look at the `inspect` module, which allows you to look through the call stack, but that is probably not a good idea unless what you're doing is writing some kind of debugging tool.

Comment: i am trying to pickle all objects in the current namespace that are from a given module, perhaps i should just explicitly ask how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`dir` returns a [sorted,standard python list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-dir-function), precisely so that you *can* manipulate it as you see fit. Just store it in a variable and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: i added more information about my specific goal, which may express the problem more accurately

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass in the results from calling dir in the namespace you're interested in?

```
def act_on_namespace(dir_result)
    for k in dir_result:
        try:
            print(eval(k).__module__)
        except:
            pass

act_on_namespace(dir())
```

Comment: this works if i define the function within the namespace, but not if i put the function in a module and try to call it that way.